# padding/margins need to be closer in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, padding, margins

So I'm trying to create a custom control based off of a flowlayoutpanel. This panel basically creates buttons that link to different forms when they open or close - you can think of it as a custom CrumbBar that's based off of a FlowLayoutPanel - I'm not using the crumbBar as the base since you can't create custom button shapes for the crumbbar.

However, my issue is that I need buttons to fit together a bit more nicely. (See picture below)

[image: On the left, you can see that the buttons are close together and arranged to kind of 'fit' together. On the right, you can see that there is some excess spacing that I would prefer to get rid of.]

On the left, you can see that the buttons are close together and arranged to kind of 'fit' together. On the right, you can see that there is some excess spacing that I would prefer to get rid of.

I've played with the padding/margins of the controls and I haven't gotten anything to work out. At the moment, my Margin and Padding is set to 0,0,0,0 for ALL controls - the main form, the custom control, the button Controls, anything that is related to this custom control has both the property set, as well as it hard coded into the code, seen below

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PremierMerchant
{
    public partial class CcCrumbBarFlow : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
    public CcCrumbBarFlow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        this.Margin = new Padding(0);
        this.Padding = new Padding(0);
    }

    public void AddButton(Form form)
    {
        //Form Main is the active form
        var mainForm = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;

        if (mainForm != null)
        {

            Button button;
            //if it's the first button, create a new Flat Arrow button
            if (mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls.Count == 0)
            {
                button = new CC_ButtonArrowShapedFlat();

            }
            //...otherwise, add a new regular arrow one
            else
            {
                button = new CC_ButtonArrowShaped();
            }
            //Set some properties
            button.Text = form.Name.ToString();
            button.Name = form.Name.ToString();
            button.Margin = new Padding(0);
            button.Height = 32;
            button.Width = 100;
            button.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                RemoveButton(form);
            };
            //add the button
            mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveButton(Form form)
    {
        //set mainform as the active button
        var mainForm = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        //for all controls, starting from the latest added one
        for (int i = mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            //if you find the control you're looking for, stop, and break
             if(mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls[i].Name == form.Name)
             {
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 //for every currently open form, starting from the back of the list
                 Form f;
                 for(int j = mainForm.openForms.Count - 1; j >= 0; j --)
                 {
                     //set the for you're looking at as the most recently opened form
                     f = mainForm.openForms[j];
                     //if this form matches a button on the crumbbar
                     if(f.Name == mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls[j].Name)
                     {
                         //remove the form, close the form, remove the control, and break
                         mainForm.openForms.Remove(f);
                         f.Close();
                         mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls.Remove(mainForm.crumbBarMainFlow.Controls[j]);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Anybody have any tips?

EDIT: Somebody mentioned using the Resize event, but my form never resizes. once it's been layed out, it's fixed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the link

Comment: You'd need negative values in the Margin, that isn't supported.  FlowLayoutPanel is not going to be useful, you have to arrange them yourself.  Use the Resize event.

Comment: Hans, doesn't that only run when the parent is resized? Unfortunately my application is full screen and would never resize. When you say that I'd have to arrange them myself, do you mean I'd have to manually set the location etc?